# Upper triangular matrices (Solving)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $T=\begin{bmatrix}A & C\\0 & B\end{bmatrix}$ is upper triangular with $A$ and $B$ upper triangular as well ($C$ is an arbitrary matrix), then what must $R$ be so that:

$$
S^{-1}TS = \begin{bmatrix}A & 0\\0 & B\end{bmatrix} \,,
$$
where $S = \begin{bmatrix}I & R\\0 & I\end{bmatrix}$?

**My attempt**

I tried to compute the equivalent statement $TS = S\begin{bmatrix}A & 0\\0 & B\end{bmatrix}$ first, which gave me:

$$
\begin{gather*}
\begin{bmatrix}A & C\\0 & B\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}I & R\\0 & I\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}I & R\\0 & I\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}A & 0\\0 & B\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}A & AR+C\\0 & B\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}A & RB\\0 & B\end{bmatrix} \\
\Rightarrow AR+C = RB
\end{gather*}
$$
then I'm stuck. How do I extract matrix $R$ from this?

I think there's probably a need to use the fact that $A$ and $B$ are upper triangular, but I don't know how. Note that this is the question as posed, I do not have the dimensions of any of the matrices.

Comment: You should have no trouble computing $S^{-1}$.  So why didn't you explicitly compute $S^{-1}TS$ from the given forms of $S$ and $T$ and set that equal to $\mathrm{diag}(A,B)$?

Comment: @EricTowers Yes, $S^{-1}$ is just the same as $S$ but with $-R$; that much I can figure out. I don't get why I should set that equal to $\mathrm{diag}(A,B)$ though? Perhaps I'm just missing something trivial..

Comment: @EricTowers Wouldn't that give the same result that OP already found?

Comment: @angryavian : It would.  It would have the advantage of actually being what he/she was told to do.

Comment: maybe you can (a) assume that $R$ is invertible (I know this is a big assumption, but just a thought) and then if you write explicit expressions for $A$ and $B$ in terms of $R$ you will conclude that for them to be upper-triangular, you need $C = R M R^{-1}$ for some $M$.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $A,B$ are triangular is not important.

We assume that $A\in M_p, spectrum(A)=(\lambda_i)_{i\leq p},B\in M_q,spectrum(B)=(\mu_i)_{i\leq q}$.

The equation in $R\in M_{p,q}$ to solve is $f(R)=RB-AR=C$; $f$ is a linear function s.t. $spectrum(f)=(-\lambda_i+\mu_j)_{i,j}$. Thus $f$ is invertible IFF for every $(i,j),$ $\lambda_i\not= \mu_j$; under these conditions, $R$ exists and is unique.

Conclusion. If $A,B$ have no common eigenvalues, then we can block-wise diagonalize $T$.

EDIT. If $g,h\in L(M_{p,q})$ are defined by $g(R)=RB,h(R)=AR$, then $f=g-h$; according to 1. and 2.2.1 in

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Abstract_properties

$spectrum(g)=(spectrum(B))^p,spectrum(h)=(spectrum(A))^q\subset \mathbb{R}^{pq}$; since $g,h$ commute, they are simultaneously triangularizable and $spectrum(f)$ is as above given. If $f$ has no zero eigenvalues, then it is bijective.

There is no closed formula for $R$; yet, to obtain $R$ it suffices to solve a linear system, that is elementary. Note that if $f$ is not bijective and $C$ is randomly chosen, then $R$ does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the attention. Do you mind expounding a little more on the third paragraph? We call $f(R)=C$, then why is it that $\mathrm{spectrum}(f)$ is the sum/subtraction of eigvals of $A$ and $B$? What about eigval of $R$? Sorry if this is extremely obvious. Also, so what is $R$ in this case? You seem to have only shown existence.

Comment: Thanks. However, is it necessarily a Kronecker product? Is there no reasonable interpretation of the question where $AR$ etc. are matrix multiplications? -> I was working under this impression, and given that Kronecker product hasn't cropped up so far in our course, I'm not quite sure that's the interpretation I need to take in this question. +1 for your help so far though!